# Why does my android app call onCreate() when sleep initiates in my view but not from home screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, sleep, activity-lifecycle

My app seems to behave perfectly except I do not understand one thing. When I press the home button and return to my app, the previous state is restored (automatically). When I press the home button and then the phone goes to sleep in the home screen (or any other view except my own) and I return to my app, the previous state is restored (automatically).

Now, the kicker is that when the phone goes to sleep with my activity on top, it does NOT automatically restore the previous state but seems to call onCreate() because the starting initialization occurs and my app behaves as if it just started.

I am able to save the instance and recall the stored state using saveInstanceState() so ultimately the problem is solvable, but my question is:
Why does Android call onCreate() if it went to sleep from my activity but not from another?
And if it does not call onCreate() what is happening and why do I have to bother with saveInstanceState() since in every instance (barring low memory) my app returns the user to their last "placemark" EXCEPT when the phone goes to sleep from my activity.

Answer (score 5):

Check whether your activity has locked the **orientation** to **portrait** or **landscape**, if you have locked the orientation, it will call **onCreate()** as it changes the orientation before it sleeps and when it wakeup.

you can solve this by adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` in to activity tag in the manifest.

```
<activity 
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation"
/>
```

Comment: Use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`.  Good call on the onCreate() being called on sleep because the orientation changes.

Answer (score 2):

When I am having issues with the life cycle methods what I would do is add onCreate,onPause,onResume etc etc in all my activities with a log.D("in onPause()") inside to trace down exactly which method is being called at what time.

Comment: It is behaving as I expected, but I still don't understand why onDestroy is called in my app when it is on top but not when it is in the back. Oh well, I guess it doesn't really matter, I don't really know how gravity works but I can use it!!! ( I'll figure it out someday, hopefully! :) )

Answer (score 0):

Android would only call onCreate if it previously destroyed your activity, in which case onDestroy would have been called. The situations where your activity state was preserved without onCreate being called were simply ones where your activity was never destroyed, it was left running the whole time.

[Here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Save/restore_instance_state) is an overview of when, and how, to save/restore your instance state.

Comment: Thanks! Being a newbie, its a little overwhelming, but knowing a bit of C && Java was super helpful. I never saw this article you referred me to. Good stuff. Still, I am not sure why onDestroy is called if SLEEP activates when my view is on top and not when my app is in the background. I just want to know WHY!!! (I can save the variables so the user experience is seemless, but...)